# удаление строки из DataGridView и БД

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, winforms, ado.net

На форме расположен tabControl. На каждой вкладке своя таблица. Проблема в том, что код на всех кнопках одинаковый а работает по-разному или не работает.
На первой, второй и третьей вкладках удаление строки из таблицы и базы работает. Код:

```
 private void DelReturnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Удалить запись?", "Удаление записи", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
           MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            int delet = Returndgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            Returndgv.Rows.RemoveAt(delet);
            Returnupdate();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Удалить запись?", "Удаление записи", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
                MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    int delet = Returndgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                    Returndgv.Rows.RemoveAt(delet);
                    Returnupdate();

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Нельзя удалить запись, т.к. она не выбрана", "Удаление записи", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Запись прекрасно удаляется и из таблицы и из базы данных SQL. На всех остальных вкладках меняется только название таблицы.
Но на последней вкладке возникает ошибка.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "Для элемента Update требуется действительный DeleteCommand при передаче коллекции DataRow с удаленными строками."
```

Код кнопки везде одинаков и везде работает. Вот с другой кнопки код

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Удалить запись?", "Удаление записи", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
           MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            int delet = Returndgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            Returndgv.Rows.RemoveAt(delet);
            Returnupdate();
            SupreturnBox.Text = "";
            ArticulBox.Text = "";
            NazvanieBox.Text = "";
            CenazakupBox.Text = "";
            DatazakupBox.Text = "";
            StatusBox.Text = "";
            DataotpravBox.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Удалить запись?", "Удаление записи", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
                MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    int delet = Returndgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                    Returndgv.Rows.RemoveAt(delet);
                    Returnupdate();
                    SupreturnBox.Text = "";
                    ArticulBox.Text = "";
                    NazvanieBox.Text = "";
                    CenazakupBox.Text = "";
                    DatazakupBox.Text = "";
                    StatusBox.Text = "";
                    DataotpravBox.Text = "";
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Нельзя удалить запись, т.к. она не выбрана", "Удаление записи", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
        }
```

а это код обновления таблицы:

```
public void Debtorubdate()
    {
        dbAdp.Update(dbTable);
        query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Debtor";
        dbAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConn);
        SqlCommandBuilder cBuilder1 = new SqlCommandBuilder(dbAdp);
        dbTable = new DataTable();
        dbAdp.Fill(dbTable);
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dbTable;
        DebtDGV.DataSource = bs;
       
    }
```

На всех вкладках работает а тут нет. Проверил ключ и что только не делал. Может что то надо обнулять dbTable или Adapter

нужно ли использовать команду

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE [condition];
```

Почему тогда без нее удаляется в первых трех таблицах и из базы тоже?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не хватало одной строки

```
public void Debtorubdate()
{
    dbAdp.Update(dbTable);
    query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Debtor";
    dbAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConn);
```

// вот здесь я удалил строку SqlCommandBuilder cBuilder1 = new SqlCommandBuilder(dbAdp);

```
    SqlCommandBuilder cBuilder1 = new SqlCommandBuilder(dbAdp);
    dbTable = new DataTable();
    dbAdp.Fill(dbTable);
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = dbTable;
    DebtDGV.DataSource = bs;
   
}
```

Как добавил ту строку что в комментах,  все заработало